# gorm - Grails MongoDB not updating a list when doing addTo/removeFrom

Tags: mongodb, grails, plugins, groovy, grails-orm

I am currently using Grails 2.5.4, with the MongoDB plugin (org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.0.0.RC2) and whenever I try to update a List of any domain class, it doesn't work.

When this code executes, the remove function succeeds and so does the save method. But the record on the database keeps the same.

```
def updateMessage(){
    String id = '-1001066675850-7184293742'
    Message message = Message.findById(id)
    def entity = message.entities.get(0)
    message.removeFromEntities(entity)
    message.save(validate: true, failOnError: true, flush: true)
    render message.entities
}
```

Message domain class is mapped like this:

```
class Message {

    User fromUser
    String text
    Chat chat
    Date sentDate
    List<MessageEntity> entities
    String sticker
    Point location
    String id
    boolean pinned = false

    static belongsTo = [entities: MessageEntity]

    static constraints = {
        chat nullable: false
        fromUser nullable: false
        sentDate nullable: false
    }

    static hasMany = [entities: MessageEntity]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
        location geoIndex: '2dsphere'
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a new list from a scratch, adding it to the Message and it still won't update.

Is there anything i'm missing on the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently updating lists was broken on either GORM for MongoDB 6.0.0.RC2 or for some particular settings on my (And a friend's) environment.

Solved it by downgrading to version 3.0.1.